# How to keep only strings which follows a specific form in a list (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, nlp

i have a corpus text extracted from pdf file defined in this list below

```
list=["7.1 PLAN COST MANAGEMENT",'Plan Cost Management is the process of defining how the project costs will be estimated','7.1.1 PLAN COST MANAGEMENT: INPUTS','Described in Section 4.2.3.1. The project charter provides the preapproved financial ','7.1.1.1 PROJECT CHARTER']
```

However , i wanted to extract only the titles found in this list which owns a specific form as shown in the example `[(d.d.d.d + upper case title) or (d.d.d + upper case title) or (d.d + upper case title)]` & getting rid of the rest. I don't really know how to encounter this properly.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does `PLAN COST MANAGEMENT: INPUTS` count as an upper case title despite the `:`? If so, can other characters like numbers or dashes be in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for regular expressions.  Here's some code to do what you're asking:

```
import re

list = ["7.1 PLAN COST MANAGEMENT",
        'Plan Cost Management is the process of defining how the project costs will be estimated',
        '7.1.1 PLAN COST MANAGEMENT: INPUTS',
        'Described in Section 4.2.3.1. The project charter provides the preapproved financial ',
        '7.1.1.1 PROJECT CHARTER']

exp = re.compile(r"(\d+(\.\d+){1,3}) +([A-Z :]+)")

for x in list:
    m = exp.match(x)
    if m:
        print(m.group(0))
```

Result:

```
7.1 PLAN COST MANAGEMENT
7.1.1 PLAN COST MANAGEMENT: INPUTS
7.1.1.1 PROJECT CHARTER
```

You weren't clear about what constitutes a valid "upper case title".  This solution assumes that the ':' character and whitespace are valid characters in a title. You can adjust what's inside the square braces in the expression to tweak what you do or do not want to consider valid characters in titles.

Comment: Wow.  That's so strange.  I had tested the code, and what you say seems so obvious that I'm surprised that I posted it that way.  I had to look to make sure someone hadn't changed my answer.  Very strange.  Don't know where my head was at. Thanks so much!

Comment: ...as far as avoiding the edge case goes...there are lots of potential edge cases.  Should we require a letter before the colon only, or both before and after?  Is there some way I can't think of to say "X where X contains at least 1 of A-Z"? I think this gives the OP the right idea, to be tweaked per a more complete definition of their problem that we don't have.

Comment: Agreed. I think this is good answer given the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, it gives the exact result you want

```
rx=re.compile(r'(\d+\.){1,3}\d+ [A-Z|\s|A-Z]+(\d+)?\n')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.